# <apex:slds /> against static resource

Tags: visualforce, static-resources, slds, date-picker, svg-icon

I'm using SLDS datepicker on my VF page. I tried `<apex:slds />` at the first place to load utility-sprite `event` icon to click and load the calendar. But it didn't load properly. Then i switched back to good old SLDS static resource. And it started loading. What could go wrong here. Here is my code. Appreciate your help.

```
<div class="slds-form-element__row">
    <div class="slds-form-element">

        <label class="slds-form-element__label boldText">Start Date</label>

        <div class="slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">

            <!-- Works with static resource but not with <apex:slds /> -->

            <svg aria-hidden="true"  class="slds-input__icon slds-input__icon--right slds-icon-text-default">
                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#event')}"></use>
            </svg>

            <!--
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-input__icon slds-icon-text-default">
                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#event" />
            </svg>
            -->
            <input id="fromdate" value="{!displayStartDate}" class="slds-input" type="Text" tabindex="8" label="From"/> 
            <apex:inputHidden id="fromHidden" value="{!startDate}"/>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried the below and it works. the key is the static resource name you need to refer is

> **$Asset.SLDS**

from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_slds.htm)

> To reference assets in the Lightning Design System, such as SVG icons
>   and other images, use the URLFOR() formula function and the
>   $Asset.SLDS global variable. To use SVG icons, add the required XML
>   namespaces by using xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" and
>   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" in the html tag.

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:slds />
    <div class="slds-form-element__row">
    <div class="slds-form-element">

        <label class="slds-form-element__label boldText">Start Date</label>

        <div class="slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">

            <!-- Works with static resource but not with <apex:slds /> -->

            <svg aria-hidden="true"  class="slds-input__icon slds-input__icon--right slds-icon-text-default">
                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#announcement')}"></use>
            </svg>




        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</apex:page>
```